# DbSet: missing added item

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In a `DbSet` entity collection of Entity Framework (6.1.3), when I add a new item, it is not returned from the collection afterwards. This is strange and unexpected. Here's some gathered sample code:

```
dbContext.Entities.ToArray();
// contains 3 entries
dbContext.Entities.Add(new Entity());
dbContext.Entities.ToArray();
// still contains 3 entries
```

How can this be? When I query `dbContext.Entities` in the immediate window in Visual Studio, it says something like "Local: Count = 4". Why does it hide the new item from me?

**Update:** If this collection doesn't do the obvious thing – returning what was added before – what do I need to do instead? It must return all records from the database when called first, and it must also include all changes (add and remove) when called later. `SaveChanges` is only called when the user has finished editing things. The collection is needed before that! `SaveChanges` might also be called somewhere in between when the user is finished editing, but the code might return and the view be displayed again at a later time.

Comment: Did you try to `context.Entities.Find(id)`?

Comment: `Entities` is just a query, `ToArray()` will materialize the query by fetching from database (and ***maybe*** merge with some locally cached result). In this case your new entity is not locally cached as well as saved to db, so it's totally out of the result.

Comment: That "Local: Count = 4" output doesn't indicate that it's cached? And when I add things, and they're not cached, how will they be saved then? Saving works fine, but I only get there after a program restart. I need new items immediately.

Comment: ***cached*** here means some item has been loaded from database before or you explicitly used `Attach` to attach some new entity BUT with some ***existing keys***. Of course `Attach` cannot add item.

Comment: again `Entities` is a `DbSet<T>` which inherits from a `DbQuery<T>`, it's a query, not a collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`DbSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) has a property `Local`. This is an `ObservableCollection` that contains all elements. The `DbSet` object itself represents just the query to the database.

From the documentation of the [`Local`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.local%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Local) property:

> Gets an ObservableCollection that represents a local view of all
>   Added, Unchanged, and Modified entities in this set. This local view
>   will stay in sync as entities are added or removed from the context.
>   Likewise, entities added to or removed from the local view will
>   automatically be added to or removed from the context.

So if you want to access the elements, always use the `Local` property to do it.

Comment: I have changed my code to `Load` all records into the `Local` collection first, then I fetch all relevant items from that. I just shouldn't forget to write the extra `.Local` or it will result in unexpected behaviour. `Add` and `Remove` still use the `DbSet` directly.

Answer (score 2):

After adding new entity, you have to Save the change using dbContext object,Use
dbContext.SaveChanges(); or dbContext.EntityState.Added

Comment: See other answer. I can't save changes now. I'm not finished with editing. How can I get all unsaved items plus saved items from that collection then?

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the changes. Try

```
dbContext.State = EntityState.Added;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I don't want to save changes in the middle of editing.

Comment: Well, the DB won't change until you save the changes. dbContext.Entities.Add(new Entity()) is just staging changes.

Comment: And to be clear: dbContext.Entities.ToArray() does query the DB, as do (I think) all other methods that do not alter the DB. The .Add(), .Delete, and (I think) all other methods that would alter the DB, do not.

Comment: How can I get all unsaved items plus saved items from that collection then?

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried just setting the State property to .Added? (The first line above). Sorry, if you can't, and that is not helpful. It'll take me minute to start a project , run a migration, and check.

Comment: The `State` property does not exist.

Comment: That is because I am an idiot; sorry. :P Try       
Entity e = new Entity();
dbContext.Entities.Add(e);
dbContext.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Added;

Comment: That doesn't help. It is already `Added` after the `Add` method.

Comment: Thought so. Sorry I couldn't help. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code to get all the items,

```
foreach (var track in dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
     if (track.State == EntityState.Deleted)
         Entity s = (Entity)track.OriginalValues.ToObject();
     else
         Entity s = (Entity)track.CurrentValues.ToObject();
}
```